# Does OAuth2 require internet access to auth provider from application server?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I want to try out Oauth2 authentication using Azure AD as the authentication provider for an application that is running on an intranet server.

The backend can't reach the internet (without a proxy). This includes `login.microsoftonline.com`. The client using the application can access intranet as well as internet.

Does OAuth2 require the server to access the authentication provider using the "default" flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the used flow. E.g. "Authorization Code Grant Flow" needs access to the token endpoint from the Service Provider (SP) location (Grafana app in your case) as well.

It is not just about metadata. Actually, some SP needs to "talk" to userinfo endpoint or introspection endpoint. So there can be a few more endpoints, which should be available.

Comment: Ah, I did forget about that :D Yeah, some flows do require access and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

It depends slightly depending on the flows used. 
Authorization code flow requires your back-end to post the received code to Azure AD so you'd need access.

In case of an API that doesn't call other APIs with Azure AD tokens, it is possible for it to not contact Azure AD at all.

But you will need to hard-code the signing keys etc that you can get through OpenID metadata at e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.
If you use the v1 endpoint/v1 tokens, you can remove the v2.0 from the URL.

Normally your app would automatically load this document on startup.
At least most of the libraries do this.

If you hard-code this information in your app, you are of course taking responsibility for updating it instead of it automatically updating.